# Jenkins - No Jenkins User, Unable to find commands

Tags: jenkins, automation, continuous-integration

I am not entirely sure I am on the right track. I have Jenkins installed on a Mac - this was installed by someone else, but I gather this is a homebrew installation. It under /Users/$USER/.jenkins

The system does not show a jenkins user, which is something I have not seen in an instance of jenkins before. Jenkins is being used to run automated builds, but consistently cannot find commands that are available via terminal when I attempt them (ex: appium, node). I am trying to launch appium via the 'execute shell' step.

I am unsure where to go from here. Using a full directory path does not seem to help.

One thing to note is that Jenkins can successfully use the Android SDK it self-installed. It installed the Android SDK even though the box it is running on already had Android SDK installed. Jenkins doesn't seem to be aware of things happening outside of its own context.

Can anyone shed some insight on what the issue may be? I have spent quite a number of hours searching and cannot seem to resolve this on my own.